# delete vertex or face leaves verts & faces instead of deleting them

Tags: modeling

This is driving me nuts.  I have a scanned OBJ file ~4M faces and I'm trying to clean it up by deleting extra geometry that isn't part of the area I care about.

I'm using edit mode > box select > face and edit > box select > vertex.  Both methods have this problem:

The selection doesn't get deleted, only some of it.  I don't know why or how, but I just want the selection to get 100% gone.

Help!
[image]

Comment: Vertexes can cover each other in solid view mode. Switch to wireframe view (press z) before selecting.

Comment: Yes!!!!! Thanks!